# Iterate over two arrays and return an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, one with names and another with id's that relate to the names.

```
arr1 = ["Bob Jones", "Steven Simon", "Green Tea"];
arr2 = [10, 8, 13];
```

The Id's in `arr2` correspond to the names in `arr1`. For example, Bob Jones has an Id of 10. What I would like to do is return a single array of objects as follows:

```
[
  {
    Id: 10,
    Name: Bob Jones
  },
  {
    Id: 8,
    Name: Steven Simon
  },
  {
    Id: 13,
    Name: Green Tea
  }
]
```

I have attempted to use `Object.defineproperties` as per the code below.

```
const myOjbect = {};

Object.defineProperties(myObject, {
  name: {
    value: arr1[0],
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
  },
  id: {
    value: arr2[0],
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true,
  },
})
```

This provides the expected result for first item in the array but I also need the subsequent items in the array to be included in the object (not just the first one).

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for `Object.defineProperty`/`defineProperties`, you can just create the objects with initializer (aka "literal") syntax in a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback:

```
const result = arr1.map((Name, index) => ({Id: arr2[index], Name}));
```

That works because `map` calls the callback function with the entry's value (the name in this case) and also its index (and also the object you called `map` on, but we're not using that), so we use the name directly and get the ID from the equivalent location in `arr2`.

In JavaScript, it would be more idiomatic for those property names to be in lower case:

```
const result = arr1.map((name, index) => ({id: arr2[index], name}));
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr1 = ["Bob Jones", "Steven Simon", "Green Tea"];
const arr2 = [10, 8, 13];
const result = arr1.map((name, index) => ({id: arr2[index], name}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you need to limit yourself to ES5-level features instead of the ES2015+ features I've used above:

```
var result = arr1.map(function(name, index) {
    return {id: arr2[index], name: name};
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr1 = ["Bob Jones", "Steven Simon", "Green Tea"];
var arr2 = [10, 8, 13];
var result = arr1.map(function(name, index) {
    return {id: arr2[index], name: name};
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with the wanted key and theit values and reduce this object by mapping the object with their new properties. This works for an arbitray count of keys. The arrays have to have the same length.

```js
var Id = [10, 8, 13],
    Name = ["Bob Jones", "Steven Simon", "Green Tea"],
    result = Object.entries({ Id, Name }).reduce((r, [k, a]) => 
        a.map((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, { [k]: v })),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using forEach loop

```js
var arr1 = ['Bob Jones', 'Steven Simon', 'Green Tea']; 
var arr2 = [10, 8, 13];
var a=[];
arr1.forEach((e,i)=>a.push({id:arr2[i], name:e}))
console.log(a)
```